# How to properly escape recipe newlines in multi-line variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

### The Question

#### Example 1

Consider the following user-defined function:

```
define func =
    if [ -f $(1) ]; then \
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; \
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
    fi
endef

all:
    $(call func,foo)
```

This will output the following:

```
$ make
if [ -f foo ]; then printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; printf "This is a rel
atively long command that"; printf " won't fit on one line\n"; fi
```

For readability, **I would like `make` to print the command on multiple lines,
as written in the Makefile.  How do I accomplish this?**

### What I've Tried

#### Example 2

The following works the way I want, but does not allow the parameterized
function:

```
filename := foo

.PHONY: foo
foo:
    if [ -f $(filename) ]; then \
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(filename)'; \
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
    fi
```

Output:

```
$ make foo
if [ -f foo ]; then \
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
fi
```

#### Example 3

My obvious first instinct was to escape the backslashes:

```
define func =
    if [ -f $(1) ]; then \\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; \\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \\
    fi
endef
```

Output:

```
$ make
if [ -f foo ]; then \\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \\
fi
/bin/sh: \: command not found
'foo' is a file
/bin/sh: line 1: \: command not found
This is a relatively long command that/bin/sh: line 2: \: command not found
 won't fit on one line
/bin/sh: line 3: \: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 127
```

#### Example 4

Okay, so why not try `\\\`?

```
$ make
if [ -f foo ]; then \ printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \ printf "This is a
relatively long command that"; \ printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \ fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 1
```

#### Example 5

Interesting.  Let's go for four...

```
$ make
if [ -f foo ]; then \\\\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \\\\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \\\\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \\\\
fi
/bin/sh: \\: command not found
'foo' is a file
/bin/sh: line 1: \\: command not found
This is a relatively long command that/bin/sh: line 2: \\: command not found
 won't fit on one line
/bin/sh: line 3: \\: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 127
```

Now we're back to where we were last time.

### What Works

#### Example 6

This is the only thing that seems to work:

```
define func =
    if [ -f $(1) ]; then #\\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; #\\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; #\\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; #\\
    fi
endef
```

Output:

```
$ make
if [ -f foo ]; then #\\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; #\\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; #\\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; #\\
fi
```

But man, that looks ugly, and it feels hackish.  There's got to be a better
way to do this.  Or am I just going about this the wrong way in the first
place?

It seems to me that `make` is just confused by the magic that happens when
escaping newlines within a recipe.  The lines printed to the terminal during
execution do not match what the shell sees.  Should this be considered a bug?

I am using GNU Make 4.2.1 on Cygwin.

### Edit

To clarify: `make` normally gives special treatment to trailing backslashes within a recipe.  They do not indicate line continuation, as they do elsewhere.  Instead, they indicate that multiple recipe lines are to be treated as a single command, and they are passed to the shell intact.

When not in a recipe, but defining a variable, this special treatment does not apply.  The lines are simply joined, as in Example 1.  This is expected.

I would expect that a double backslash would be translated to a single literal backslash in the variable, but instead both backslashes are retained.  When the variable is expanded in the recipe, I would expect `make` to behave as if the recipe had `\\` at the end of every line.  If this were the case, each line would be executed separately.  But as you can see from Examples 3 and 6, the lines are executed together.

The point is, it is possible to get magic backslash parsing from the expansion of a variable.  The problem is the mechanics of this behavior are inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: When make reads the makefile, it discards the backslashes as it's reading, so it has no knowledge they were ever there afterwards.   While I understand the motivation of what you're doing (it would make it easier to read what make is doing), it's not really practical, and if you're really debugging, then you want to debug what make is actually doing.

Comment: BTW, that last example is treated as `if [ -f $(1) ]; then #` followed by a long comment on my version of make...

Comment: @HardcoreHenry [Line continuations within a recipe are an exception](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html).  They are not discarded, and they are passed to the shell intact. (See my second example.)

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using the backslashes inside a variable. If I read the manual correctly, this is a different place (i.e. one with no special handling) than recipe lines which are subject to the dont-remove-backslashes exceptions.

Comment: @Vroomfondel You're exactly right when using a single backslash, as in my first example.  However, the double backslash is given special treatment in examples 3, 5 and 6.  `make` must have detected the trailing backslash in the recipe, or it would have treated each line as a separate command.

Comment: BTW are these complex shell scripts that you are trying to execute.? You can get quite far within make and are Windows compatible as a bonus.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Nothing complicated. I'm using this in my clean commands to automatically delete directories if there are no files left in them after cleaning. It doesn't actually matter very much, it's just triggering my OCD lol. Other than this, my makefile is so perfect and clean!

Comment: Added a ticket http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?63172 around make target -n not printing correctly within a make function which may be related to this question

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer Definitely related, but are you sure `-n` has anything to do with it? Does your example behave differently without it?

Comment: @JoshKlodnicki you're right. I suppose the `-n` only shows the unformatted command and without it, the make target run also shows an unformatted command. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nicer (albeit still hacky) solution that seems to work:

```
define func =
    if [ -f $(1) ]; then $\\
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; $\\
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; $\\
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; $\\
    fi
endef

all:
    @echo vvvvvvvv
    $(call func,foo)
    @echo ^^^^^^^^
```

Output:

```
$ make
vvvvvvvv
if [ -f foo ]; then \
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
fi
'foo' is a file
This is a relatively long command that won't fit on one line
^^^^^^^^
```

I think this is how it works:

1. During the first scan for line continuations, the `$` is ignored, so the
   parser sees `\\`, assumes the backslash is escaped, and leaves the lines
   intact.
2. When expanding the function, `$\` is recognized as a variable.  Assuming
   you haven't actually assigned a variable named `\`, this expands to
   nothing.
3. Now we are left with a single backslash at the end of the line, which is
   treated as if it were literally typed into the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

Urk! This is due to *make*'s noddy parser.

Recipes are stored as-is.
They are expanded as-and-when *make* is about to call the shell.
Once the entire recipe has been expanded,
the first line is passed to a shell.
If that command succeeds, then the second is run.
Wash, rinse, repeat.
Backslashes at the end of line are preserved,
with the effect that the following line is passed at the same time as the first.

In recursive variable definition however,
backslashes at the end of line are removed *as the definition is read*

```
define oneline =
  aa \
  bb \
  cc
endef

$(error [$(value oneline)])
```

which gives

`$ make
Makefile:9: *** [  aa bb cc].  Stop.`

### What we are aiming for

We need to massage *make*'s syntax so that a variable expands to *exactly* this text:

```
target:
    if [ -f foo ]; then \
        printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \
        printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
        printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
    fi
```

which we then simply feed to *make* via something like

```
$(eval ${var})
```

### Backslashes

Just replace each *newline* with a *space*-*backslash*-*newline*-*tab* quad using `$(subst)`.

A function to do that:

```
empty :=
tab := ${empty}   # Trailing tab
define \n :=


endef

stanza = $(subst ${\n}, \${\n}${tab})
```

To check it works:

```
define func =
  if [ -f $1 ]; then
    printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$1';
    printf "This is a relatively long command that";
    printf " won't fit on one line\n";
  fi
endef

$(error [$(call stanza,$(call func,foo))])
```

giving:

`Makefile:23: *** [  if [ -f foo ]; then \
            printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \
            printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
            printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
          fi].  Stop.`

Note that the definition of `func` now has no annotation at the end of its lines.

### Putting it all together

```
define \n :=


endef
empty :=
tab := ${empty}        # Trailing tab

stanza = $(subst ${\n}, \${\n}${tab},$1)

define func =
  if [ -f $1 ]; then
    printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$1';
    printf "This is a relatively long command that";
    printf " won't fit on one line\n";
  fi
endef

define rule =
  target:
        echo vvv
        $(call stanza,$(call func,foo))
        echo ^^^
endef

$(eval ${rule})
```

Leading to

`$ touch foo; make -R --warn
echo vvv
vvv
if [ -f foo ]; then \
    printf "'%s' is a file\n" 'foo'; \
    printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \
    printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \
  fi
'foo' is a file
This is a relatively long command that won't fit on one line
echo ^^^
^^^`

An interesting academic exercise.
Still can't put literal backslashes in either :)

Comment: +1 for accomplishing the goal. I take it it is impossible to do this without using `eval` on the whole rule? It makes it difficult in integrate into a larger script.

Comment: @JoshKlodnicki Personally I don't see this as a loss. Long runs of shell syntax in a makefile are pretty smelly TBH. They can nearly always be replaced by _make_ machinery, or helper shell scripts. The former is certainly to be preferred over the latter. (I was interested only from an academic point of view. If it's really important to you then `.ONESHELL` is probably what you want.)

Comment: Agreed, it's not that important. I'm just a little annoyed that make doesn't work the way I want it to.  I hadn't heard of `.ONESHELL`, thanks for that.

Comment: Probably `.RECIPEPREFIX` should be used instead of defining the `tab` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
define newline :=
$(strip)
$(strip)
endef

define func =
    if [ -f $(1) ]; then \$(newline)\
       printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; \$(newline)\
       printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \$(newline)\
       printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \$(newline)\
    fi
endef

func2 = if [ -f $(1) ]; then \$(newline)   printf "'%s' is a file\n" '$(1)'; \$(newline)   printf "This is a relatively long command that"; \$(newline)   printf " won't fit on one line\n"; \$(newline)fi

all:
    $(call func,foo)
    @echo --------------
    $(call func2,foo)
```

The first one seems to be space-stripped. The second looks nice at the output but.. oh well, seems like being stuck between a rock and a hard place :/

Comment: It's an improvement, but it's not exactly elegant.  Good idea though.  If I don't get a better solution, I'll give it to you.